# how to place multiple figures/tables in one table cell

Tags: tables, positioning, subfloats, two-column, ieeetran

How can i place my figures and tables the way the picture shows in a two-column text environment (IEEEtran)?

[image]

I tried the `table*` into `tabular` but it did not work out...

Here is the code i came up with. Somehow the figures on the right side do not align with the one on the left and then again this example does not have captions and i wanted to place a table in the upper right box instead of a dummy figure.

```
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{BigFigure} &
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}       
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{DUMMYFigure} \\          
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{SmallFigure}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show us the code you already have so that we do not have to write everything from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the size of the big figure (including the caption), so the right-hand side box can be adjusted to it.

```
\documentclass[comsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure*}
\centering

% measure the height of the big figure
\sbox0{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \vfill
  \caption{Caption of big figure}
  \end{minipage}}
\usebox{0}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{.48\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Caption of table}
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
\hline
A & B & C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\vfill

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image}

\caption{Caption of small figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[6-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{0.6\textwidth}@{}P{0.4\textwidth}@{}}
\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Caption of big figure}
    &   
        \captionof{table}{Caption of table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        A & B & C & D\\
        \hline
        A & B & C & D\\
        \hline
        A & B & C & D\\
        \hline
        A & B & C & D\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}

        \medskip
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \medskip
        \captionof{figure}{Caption of small figure}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[4-10]
    \end{document}
```

I obtain the following figure:

[image]

In above code I use

- `{figure*}` for float environment, which span two columns. In text it will appear on the next page on the top (with option `[t]`) or on the bottom (with option`[b]`)
- for caption I use `\captionof{figure}{....}` for figure and `\captionof{table}{....}` for table.
- by help of `[export]{adjustbox}` is the baseline of the first figure set to top: `\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.9\linewidth]{...}`