# Two figures (with one spanning over two columns) and a table arranged together

Tags: tables

I want to create the following figure:
[image]

The top figure should span over two columns (this is 2 column document).

A similar question has been answered here (see accepted answer): [how to place multiple figures/tables in one table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295271/how-to-place-multiple-figures-tables-in-one-table-cell)

But their positioning is different and I could not get it to work the way I need it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummytext. do not use in real document.

\begin{document}
\lipsum \lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```